# AS3 button not hiding

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, visible

I have a button which I want to use to mute audio, which will change to a un-mute icon when it is clicked, and toggle back and forth.

The thing is, its still visible in the stage after my code.  The weirdest bit is that if I trace the visibility after I call the function, it actually says that its hidden: but its clearly visible on the stage.

```
play_pause.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, change_sound);

function change_sound (e:MouseEvent):void{
        fl_NS.soundTransform = muteAudio;
        e.target.visible = false;
        trace(play_pause.visible);
        muted = true;
}
```

Here are some other things I've tried which didn't work:

```
play_pause.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, change_sound);

function change_sound (e:MouseEvent):void{
        fl_NS.soundTransform = muteAudio;
        play_pause.visible = false;
        trace(play_pause.visible);
        muted = true;
}
```

Another version:

```
play_pause.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, change_sound);

function change_sound (e:MouseEvent):void{
        fl_NS.soundTransform = muteAudio;
        play_pause.gotoAndPlay(2);
        muted = true;
}
```

No visual change again. Just to state some key points:

- my movieclip is *definitely* called `play_pause`
- it traces that it is visible before the click, and invisible after the click (the trace statement comes back false) but there is no visual change
- the function definitely fires

I haven't used AS3 for a while, I'm guessing I'm making a really noob mistake?  Full code: http://pastebin.com/RirGdS1w

Link to .fla file: http://db.tt/51DD0Fbl

Comment: try play_pause.gotoAndPlay(2); to 'play_pause.gotoAndStop (2);' it works like a timeline, if u ask it to play it will skip to the next frame until it's told to stop.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to look

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps someone else could fully explain this, but I found that once the **SWF was embedded into an HTML page** it worked as expected.  It was when it was **being run in Flash CS5.5** that it wasn't working.  This will now be a nightmare to debug but for the purposes of the project tonight I have it working.

Answer (score 0):

Try **e.currentTarget** inside the listener function

*target* is the deepest element, like a moviclip inside another movieclip

*currentTarget* is the one associated with the addEventListener method

Comment: I did try e.currentTarget, should have put it above - I'm beginning to think this is a Flash bug, as everything worked fine once embedded in the browser. thanks